# how to make suspend calls "wait" for a blocking thread inside, in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Let me explain it better...

I have a suspended function

```
suspend fun foo(){
   if(startFlag){
     myMethod()
    }
}
```

when I call `myMethod()` on the first time I will check for the value of `startFlag` and if it is false will call myMethod.

I cannot use a `init {}` for this, must be when I call `foo()` the first time (due more complex logic).

My problem:

At the first time I call `foo()` will call `myMethod()` (lets says it takes a long time to resolve)

Then another call is made to `foo()`, I want to detect that `myMethod()` is already running in a thread and I should wait for it.

But since `fun foo()` is itself suspended, not sure if I can do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: would you be able to share more code? e.g. entire class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting problem and I want to share an approach to solve it, hoping this will help.

#### Basic Solution

You can restore the `myMethod()` computation using a `Deferred`. Basically the code could look like this:

```
    val myMethodDeferred = GlobalScope.async {
        myMethod()
    }

    suspend fun foo(){
        myMethodDeferred.await()
    }
```

The `async` function returns a `Deferred` object that holds the computation of `myMethod`. When you call `myMethodDeferred.await()` it waits for the end of the computation and returns the result of `myMethod` (for using it if needed).

If you want the computation to be done only when calling `foo()` you could add a parameter to the `async` call like this: `async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY){ ...`. It will cause the computation to lazily start on the first `.await()` call.

(The `GlobalScope` could be replaced with any `CoroutineScope`, or with a scope that is passed as constructor parameter to the class. If `myMethod()` is not a suspending function but a blocking function as you described, you may want to use an appropriate CoroutineScope, for example `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` if it does an I/O computation.)

#### Handling Failures

The downside of this solution is when `myMethod()` failed with exception. If `myMethod()` failed, the failure will be stored in the deferred, and every call to `foo()` will fail too, instead of trying to run `myMethod()` again.

To handle failures of `myMethod()`, I suggest to declare a class with a name `Retryable` that will hold a computation that can be retried, similarly to how `Deferred` hold a computation. The code:

```
class Retryable<T>(private val computation: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) {

    private var deferred: Deferred<T>? = null

    suspend fun await(): T {
        val oldDeferred = deferred
        val needsRetry = oldDeferred == null || oldDeferred.isCompleted && oldDeferred.getCompletionExceptionOrNull() != null
        if (needsRetry) {
            deferred = GlobalScope.async(block = computation)
        }
        return deferred!!.await()
    }

}
```

The usage should look like this:

```
    val myMethodRetryable = Retryable { myMethod() }

    suspend fun foo(){
        myMethodRetryable.await()
    }
```

Now, every call to `foo()` will wait to the computation of `myMethod()` to be completed, but if it has already end with failure it will re-run it and wait for the new computation.

(Here, the `CoroutineScope` should be passed as parameter to the `Retryable`, but I don't want to complicate the sample code.)

---

#### Alternative Solution: Use asynchronous factory function

Since `myMethod()` should only be called once, if you cannot call it on `init {}` you can instead call it on a factory function.

Example code:

```
class MyClass(private val myMethodResult: String) {
  companion object {
    suspend fun create(): MyClass {
        val myMethodResult = myMethod()
        return MyClass(myMethodResult)
     }
     private suspend fun myMethod(): String {
        ...
     }
  }
  ...
}
```

It is useful if you can init `MyClass` once from a suspending function before using it.

(If `myMethod()` is not a suspending function but a blocking function as you described, you may want to wrap it with an appropriate context, for example `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { myMethod() }` if it does I/O computation.)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a [`Semaphore`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/).

```
...

suspend fun foo(semaphore: Semaphore) = semaphore.withPermit {

    if (startFlag) {
        myMethod()
    }
}
...
```

then create and pass as argument a `Semaphore` with 1 permit.

```
val myJobSemaphore = Semaphore(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you right, it can be done with `Mutex` for example:

```
var startFlag = true
val mutex = Mutex()

suspend fun foo() = mutex.withLock {
    if (startFlag) {
        myMethod()
        startFlag = false
    }
}
```

here is link to [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Y0H_dfL24)